# What word means being forced to agree or accept?

Tags: single-word-requests

How to say something like I am forced to agree or accept the situation in one word?

I believe there is a precise word to express this.

Comment: A possible plain-speaking could be to use **had:** *I had to agree/ accept ...*

Comment: Please show us how you might wish to use this in a sentence. Otherwise it is not possible to tell whether you want a a noun or a verb or whatnot.

Comment: This is mostly a thesaurus-hunt, one which some may feel is very close to being answerable as a simple matter of General Reference. You could be [resigned](http://thesaurus.com/browse/resigned) to the situation, or [yield](http://thesaurus.com/browse/yield) to it in [surrender](http://thesaurus.com/browse/surrender). You could be [coerced](http://thesaurus.com/browse/coerce) or [compelled](http://thesaurus.com/browse/compelled), or you could just plain [give in](http://thesaurus.com/browse/give%20in) because of your interlocutor’s powers of [persuasion](http://thesaurus.com/browse/persuasion).

Comment: You agreed "under duress", or were "coerced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the reasons, one of the following words may make sense.

1. Coerced
2. Blackmailed
3. Compelled
4. Required
5. Held hostage
6. Obligated or bound

Answer (score 4):

[*Coercion*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coerce) is a common word for being forced against one’s will.

> to compel or restrain by force or authority without regard to individual wishes or desires; to compel by force or intimidation.
>   
>         ―Free Dictionary

Likewise *compel* is used the same way, but is less forceful: to force, drive, or constrain: to necessitate or pressure by force.

> In 1968, George Whitmore, Jr. was beaten by New York police and coerced to signing a 61 page confession that he murdered two women.
>   
>         ―*New York Times Editorial: Who Will Mourn George Whitmore, Jr?*
>
> Now that I was compelled to think about it, reading was something that just came to me, as learning to fasten the seat of my union suit without looking around, or achieving two bows from a snarl of shoelaces.
>   
>         ―Harper Lee, *To Kill a Mockingbird*

Comment: Thanks. But I want something like that but a bit polite way.

Answer (score 1):

A exact equivalent is *to bludgeon someone into doing something*

> Bludgeon:
>
> [...]
>
> 1.1 Force or bully (someone) to do something: she was determined not to be bludgeoned into submission
>
> No one, however, has reported on the extent to which voters were
>   bludgeoned into voting one way or another by various local thugs
>
> Most of these civil societies have been bludgeoned into silence by
>   their regimes, with even the more representative systems denying their
>   citizens true political participation.
>
> Mark was a State employee with no criminal history before he was
>   indicted for a crime that he did not commit and now his family are
>   financially ruined and he has been bludgeoned into signing a plea
>   bargain by the legal vampires.

Answer (score 1):

Acquiesce, essentially to agree without protest, yet you'd prefer something else

Comment: Acquiescence is still voluntary though. You may be acting against your wishes/preferences, but you're choosing to do so (i.e. not being forced).